# Ubuntu 13.10 no longer boots, stuck at grub boot prompt (sdb hdd that ubuntu's installed on is no longer detected)

Tags: boot, grub2

Ubuntu 13.10 has been running fine since I installed it on my external harddrive a few weeks ago. However, yesterday while Ubuntu was running, I accidentally knocked the external harddrive off the table and a cable (power plugged into usb socket) detached. Portions of the screen went grey and the system froze. I had to turn the laptop off by holding down the power button.

I plugged the cable back in and started up the laptop. However, instead of the usual option to boot Ubuntu, I got the gnu grub2 boot prompt. I have actually had this happen a couple of times before, but after plugging everything back in, Ubuntu would boot normally. This time, though, no such luck.

I have booted from the cd I used to install Ubuntu from and selected the option to try without installing. Once there, I ran `sudo fdisk -l` from the terminal. Here are the results:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60563 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbb8b9976

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

As you can see above, my sdb external harddrive is not detected. Disconnecting/reconnecting it seems to make no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you broke it when you knocked it off the table. Try plugging it into another computer, is it seen there?

Comment: Thanks very much for your swift reply, terdon. I fear you're right - the hard drive is not recognised by the other computer.